# Can anyone explain about iReport in Java?

Tags: java, netbeans, ireport

1. Is it a good report generator?
2. Is there an iReport plugin for NetBeans?
3. What are the good tutorials that I can use to learn about iReport?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iReport is one of best report generators for Java. Specially it's free and open source.

There is a [NetBeans plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/4425/ireport).

Comment: How about the tutorial?? can you give some good online tutorials for this?? (specially for netbeans)

Comment: http://ireport-tutorial.blogspot.com/2009/01/subreport-in-ireport-for-netbeans.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Jasper Reports is **one of the best reporting tools** written in **Java** for use in **Java** applications.
For tutorials look on the Jasper reports website [Documentation](http://jasperforge.org/website/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/documentation.html?header=project&target=jasperreports).